# ClassNotFoundException in bootstrap.php.cache Symfony2

Tags: symfony, netbeans-platform

I just updated my composer after running my project it shows error in boostrap.cache file `ClassNotFoundException` I am currently using Netbeans on Windows.

> Attempted to load class "ClassCollectionLoader" from namespace "Symfony\Component\ClassLoader".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

I tried command:

```
php bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

It gives me error:

> could not open input file: bin/build_bootstrap.php

Clearing cache gave me errors like:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www\TEST\app/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\TEST\app\autoload.php on line 11
>   PHP Warning:  require_once(C:\wamp\www\TEST\app/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\TEST\app\autoload.php on line 11
>   PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www\TEST\app/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\TEST\app\autoload.php on line 11

```
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
if (!class_exists('Composer\\Autoload\\ClassLoader', false)) {
    $loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
} else {
    $loader = new Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
    $loader->register();
}
// intl
if (!function_exists('intl_get_error_code')) {
    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php';
    $loader->add('', __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs');
}
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists');
return $loader;
```

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Comment: clearing cache gave me following errors:
i will write the errors above

Comment: What was the output of command `composer update`?

Comment: it installed all symfony tools such as symfony.doctrine-bridge(v2.6.7) etc and generated autoload files

Comment: Without any error or warning?

Comment: Did you try to clear cache manually by removing files in `app/cache/dev`?

Comment: without any error it showed error of git only but i am not using git

Comment: If you have any error (even that you don't understand) it is not successfull! Your `composer update` failed because you didn't install git. And this is the main problem!

Comment: sir how to install properly then why is it showing git error

Comment: Ok. I answered with solution to your problem but next time you need to post all the errors that you receive (EVEN IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHY THEY WAS RECEIVED)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to install git. The latest version for Windows you can find [here](https://git-scm.com/download/win).

After that you need to set up `PATH` variable to find your git executable.

Then you need to run `composer update`.

I would also recommend you to install `svn` too. Because in some cases you can meet some libraries that use it yet.

Comment: composer updated without any error
seems like my problem is in vendor folder its giving error in autoload.php
at line 11
autoload.php code is posted in my question above

Comment: Error occurs while you trying to load some page? Or when? Did you install APC or some other OpCache engine?

Comment: when i load the page it gives me ClassNotFoundException in bootstrap.php.cache 
when i clear cahce it gives me error at  autoload,php line 11

Comment: What about OpCache? Can you post somewhere on the web your `phpinfo` information?